# I get a 401 error when accessing GCD via a URL

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have tried to access the following URL but when I typed it into a browser I get the message:

> "not found"

When I use it in my Talend rest component I get the error message:

> 401 error.

https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/my-project/runQuery?key=AIzaSyCA_j4WyyEn-3Q0NzWNcmcoqCrRw17EC1Y

An idea?

Answer (score 1):

All the Cloud Datastore API methods expect POST requests. That's why you get an error when you access the URL via the browser.

The 401 error is because you need to provide credentials to access the Cloud Datastore API. You can find more information about client libraries that will help you do that on the [Cloud Datastore Getting Started page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate) or the [Google APIs Client Libraries page](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries).